# How to downgrade a flutter to a specific version?

Tags: flutter

I currently have flutter 3.3.5 and I'm trying to upgrade it to 3.7.11 but the problem is I don't think there's a way to upgrade to a specific version.

So instead I upgrade to 3.10.5 and try to downgrade the version to the 3.7.11

Im using

> flutter downgrade v3.7.11

to downgrade it to a specific version, but everytime it will ask me "Downgrade flutter to version 3.3.5"

I can't find a way to achieve my purpose. Please help

Comment: https://fvm.app/

Answer (score 1):

flutter downgrade  (example: flutter downgrade v3.7.11)

Comment: this created a loop of error and re-try inside my terminal, but after restarting the android studio I used the flutter doctor and it started to download the downgrade version i needed. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and control multiple flutter versions through Flutter Version Management (FVM) :

https://fvm.app/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path of Flutter in `~/.zshrc` file. Whatever Flutter version you set in `~/.zshrc` that will be your Flutter version on your system.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Open terminal and Navigate to the flutter location

`cd <flutter_path>`

Step 2:
Now enter the command

`git checkout <version>`
You can find all the releases from this link https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases

Step 3:
Now run `flutter doctor -v` command so flutter will download the stuff related to the particular version

`flutter doctor -v`Once the flutter doctor command is successful you can go ahead and enjoy the version you wish

Comment: After doing the above, `flutter doctor` warns:

"Currently on an unknown channel. Run `flutter channel` to switch to an official channel."

Is this harmful? Am I missing something?